# change picture on click bitmap

Tags: blackberry, bitmap, onclick

How can I change the bitmap `check_box1`  by another `check_box2`  on click the bitmap `check_box1`

```
btmp_on = EncodedImage
            .getEncodedImageResource("btn_check_on.png");

    btmp_off = EncodedImage
            .getEncodedImageResource("btn_check_off.png");
    Bitmap check_box1 = getScaledBitmapImage(btmp_off,30,40);
    Bitmap check_box2 = getScaledBitmapImage(btmp_on,30,40);
```

Comment: based on what you told me, I can understand that you are using a CustomBitmapField which extends Field. I suggest you to make CustomBitmapField extend BitmapField and override public void setBitmap(Bitmap _bmp) method. and your bitmap to setBitmap(Bitmap bmp) to change the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this below link:

[For CustomListField](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/list-with-separators-like-options/m-p/1558767#M190787)

and for touch device add the same code in the **fieldChanged** to **touchEvent**
like:

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) 
{
    switch( message.getEvent() ) 
    {          
        case TouchEvent.CLICK:
            clickButton();
            break;

        default: break;
    }
    return super.touchEvent(message);
}
private void clickButton()
{
    Field focussedOne=this.getLeafFieldWithFocus();//Means this is the last field which is not having any otherFields;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(focussedOne==listStyleButtonField[i])
        {
            if(listStyleButtonField[i].getChanged())
                listStyleButtonField[i].changeBitmap(bitmap,false);
            else
                listStyleButtonField[i].changeBitmap(bitmapHover,true);
        }
    }
}
```